# wkhtmltopdf (pdfkit) Could not connect to any X display

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf with Django ,nginx,uwsgi
it works perfectly on development env running using manage.py runserver 
but when serving with nginx ans uwsgi i get this error:

```
wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-isp'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.

Exception Location:     /home/isp/Env/isp/lib/python3.6/site-package/pdfkit/pdfkit.py in to_pdf, line 159
```

the command :

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com output.pdf
```

works perfectly on terminal 
and i used this guid to deploy the Django app
    https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04#setting-up-the-uwsgi-application-server

i think it is related to virtualenv , i tried using this wrapper 
https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Using-wkhtmltopdf-without-X-server

but still having the same error

mycode :

```
import pdfkit
    pdfkit.from_file("./invoices/invoice"+str(booking_id)+"-"+str(invoice_id)+".html", "invoices/invoice_initial"+str(booking_id)+"-"+str(invoice_id)+".pdf")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Solution

Instead of using

```
apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

I downloaded the latest version from the [releases page](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) and everything works now.

Comment: After installing the latest version we also need to add option {"xvfb": ""}

Comment: Worked for me straight away. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Download the latest version from [the official page](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

```
sudo wget -p ./ https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
```

It worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 8):

You have 2 approaches to solve this problem.

1. `os.system("xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf %s %s"%(INPUT_URL, OUTPUT_FILE_PATH))`
2. Using `pyvirtualdisplay`:

   ## Installation:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install xvfb 
   $ sudo pip install pyvirtualdisplay
   ```

   ## Then:

   ```
   from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
   import pdfkit
   try:
      display.start()
      pdfkit.from_string(input_html_string, output_file_path)
      # pdfkit.from_url(input_url, output_file_path)
   finally:
      display.stop()
   ```

Comment: I think one needs to instantiate the display?

Comment: you can simplify as: 
with Display():
  pdfkit.from_string(input_html_string, output_file_path)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with X11 forwarding. You need to enable it on the server.

Check [this](https://www.e2enetworks.com/help/knowledge-base/x11-forwarding/) out.