# Conversion of HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf failed

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf

For setup I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
pip install pdfkit==0.6.1
```

Now, I am trying to run the following code on a VM in the cloud:

```py
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file("foo.html", "foo.pdf", options={"javascript-delay": 10000})
```

The javascript-delay argument is necessary because otherwise some parts are not rendered correctly. This command works fine on my local machine, but in the cloud I get the following error message:

```
wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Any idea how to fix this error OR ideas about an alternative way of converting an .html to a .pdf?

Comment: Well, the error line says that it could not find a display. Are you sure it should be able to run in the cloud?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wkhtmltopdf (pdfkit) Could not connect to any X display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787618/wkhtmltopdf-pdfkit-could-not-connect-to-any-x-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, this is what I added to my Dockerfile to make it work:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq gdebi

RUN TEMP_DEB="$(mktemp).deb" \
  && wget -O "$TEMP_DEB" 'https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.1.4-2/wkhtmltox_0.12.1.4-2.bionic_amd64.deb' \
  && sudo apt install -yqf "$TEMP_DEB" \
  && rm -f "$TEMP_DEB"
```

So basically installing `gdebi` and then installing a different version of `wkhtmltox`.